# Replace to another column if exits in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a HTML table having values from Mysql. My HTML table looks like this

```
-------   ------   ------   ------
 type      name     b_id     Edit
-------   ------   ------   ------
Laptop     mac      E1:23    edit
Desktop    dell     D2:45    edit
```

I am inserting values from input textboxes for type and name. And a select dropdown for b_id.
I can edit each row values by clicking `edit`and i have a dropdown displaying all my `b_id's`.

I need to update b_id values so that, if it already exists replace with new delete the old.

For suppose i'l hit edit on **Desktop** **dell** row. And i'l select E1:23(which is already mapped for **laptop mac**). On saving this, **E1:23** should map to desktop dell and previous mapping (laptop mac) should be **deleted**. I mean it should be empty

My Query

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // Auto Increment
$b_id = $_REQUEST['b_id']; //b_id from select dropdown on edit
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE b_id='$b_id'";
$rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
$rs=parent::getAll($rs);
if($rs) // if b_id already exists
{
    //First empty old b_id which has mapped already
    $sql2 = "UPDATE table_name SET b_id='$b_id' WHERE id='$id'";
    $rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
}
```

So how to empty previous mapped b_id. Not the type and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to empty the data in b_id, your query should be something like this:

```
if($rs) // if b_id already exists
{
    //First empty old b_id which has mapped already
    $sql2 = "UPDATE table_name SET b_id='' WHERE b_id='$b_id'";
    $rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql2);
}
```